# How to understand the non-abelian DBI action?

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, branes, trace

I'm reading chapter 7 in "String Theory and M-theory, A Modern Introduction" by Becker, Becker and Schwarz. It says that the understanding of the square root of the determinant is to compute the determinant of each of the $N^2$ matrix elements. (See below) However, I think the gauge invariant is violated if we compute the trace of the square root in this way. How can I understand it and is there any reference about this way of understanding?

(Actually, I know that in many literature, the non-abelian case is understood as an expansion where one should use the symmetric trace.)

[image]